# Getting time length of youtube video file

Tags: php, javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I am having a problem. how to get the time duration of youtube video?
Here is the scenario.

> I have a input field in this field say i enter youtube url now i want
>   to put a validation that video should only be of 1 min, if yes then i
>   store this in database else i show an error message.

is it possible to do this thing?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the data API to get the information for a video. You might need to extract the video's identifier from the URL.

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html#Retrieving_Video_Entry

If you're using Zend, there's already a class to do the heavy lifting:

```
<?php
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php'; // the Zend dir must be in your include_path
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
$videoEntry = $yt->getVideoEntry('the0KZLEacs');
$duration = $videoEntry->getVideoDuration();
```

If not, you can go to `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$videoId}` and get an XML document to process yourself.

For example, http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/KURI9EQV3dY returns an XML document for a video which contains information including the duration: `<yt:duration seconds='153'/>`

Comment: Unfortunately using `gdata.youtube.com` from youtube.com won’t work (at least for userscripts) because Chrome blocks it as “insecure”—even though they’re their own sodding domains. `:-/`

Answer (score 4):

Per their docs, `In a video feed entry, the <yt:duration> tag specifies a video's length.`

Comment: Use the url and the data api (http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html) and you'll get the above information

Answer (score 1):

The code below will get you the video thumbnail, title, and duration, FROM THE URL. Just change the youtube link from the end.

Demo: http://100ro.ro/wp-includes/ajaxdemo/test.php?y=www.youtube.com/watch?v=V80jm1rs2UQ  :

(**note: use the youtube url in y=youtubeurl without http://** )

```
<?php

      getYoutubeImage($_GET["y"]);

            function getYoutubeImage($e){
            //GET THE URL
            $url = $e;

            $queryString = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);

            parse_str($queryString, $params);

            $v = $params['v'];  




        // function to parse a video <entry>
        function parseVideoEntry($entry) {      
          $obj= new stdClass;

          // get nodes in media: namespace for media information
          $media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
          $obj->title = $media->group->title;
          $obj->description = $media->group->description;



          // get <yt:duration> node for video length
          $yt = $media->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
          $attrs = $yt->duration->attributes();
          $obj->length = $attrs['seconds']; 


          // return object to caller  
          return $obj;      
        }   

        // get video ID from $_GET 
        if (!isset($v)) {
          die ('ERROR: Missing video ID');  
        } else {
          $vid = $v;
        }

        // set video data feed URL
        $feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $v;

        // read feed into SimpleXML object
        $entry = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);

        // parse video entry
        $video = parseVideoEntry($entry);

        // display video image, title and duration
        echo "<img src='http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/$v/default.jpg' width='150' />";
        echo "<p>{$video->title}</p>";
        echo "<p>".sprintf("%0.2f", $video->length/60) . " min. </p>";


        } 

        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL of the video will contain the video ID. You can use this ID when requesting video information using [YouTube's API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html). In the video feed response you get back there should be a `<yt:duration>` tag that you can use to get the duration of the video. Just take a bit to go over the API and you should be able to find what you need.